# Do I need to learn haskell to write plutus in Cardano?

Tags: smartcontracts, cardano, plutus

https://cardanodocs.com/technical/plutus/introduction/

Should I learn plutus? I believe it is a language whereby I can write smart contracts on Cardano

Answer (score 1):

Plutus is a haskell framework for compiling Smart Contract code in order to run on the cardano blockchain. In as much as you need to know Javascript in order to learn React Js you will need to learn functional programming (haskell, scala, etc) in order to write for plutus.

Answer (score 0):

As per docs said:

> Plutus is the native smart contract language for Cardano. It is a Turing-complete language written in Haskell, and Plutus smart contracts are effectively Haskell programs. By using Plutus, you can be confident in the correct execution of your smart contracts. It draws from modern language research to provide a safe, full-stack programming environment based on Haskell, the leading purely-functional programming language.

So, if you want to feel confident programming Plutus, it's recommended to learn Haskell.

Answer (score -2):

Plutus is similar to Haskell, but it is not Haskell.  You don't need to learn one to learn the other.   Moreover, Plutus is still in development, the language that the Cardano testnet currently supports is Solidity.   My guess is that they will be supporting Solidity for a long time, even after Plutus gets released.   So, strictly speaking, you don't even need to learn Plutus to write smart contracts on Cardano.

Comment: That's not correct. In order to write smart contracts on cardano, you should learn plutus, it's the only way.